# Using both chrome extension manifest & pwa manifest in Angular 6

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular6, manifest, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to use one Angular app for both PWA and chrome extension? Because both, extension's and PWA's configuration require a unique and mutually exclusive `manifest.json` and we cannot place two manifest files in the root of one Angular project.

What should be the way out from this situation?

Answer (score 1):

A [web app manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) doesn't have to be `manifest.json`. In fact it could be just about anything. `pwa.json` or `manifest.webmanifest` would work just as well. You then need to update the `link` tag in your site HTML to point to that file.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
```

Comment: The filename may be different, but then, in HTML we cannot give two manifest links, right?

Comment: Chrome extensions assume the file is `manifest.json` in the root of the packaged directory. They don't care what manifest the HTML links to.

Comment: The question is that, is it possible to include two manifest files in one project(to make sure one is used for chrome extension and one for PWA). The solution cannot be to tell `index.html` to link to two different manifest files.

Comment: As I said, Chrome extensions don't use the HTML file to find the `manifest.json` file. Linking to the Chrome extension manifest from HTML won't do anything. Extensions find it based purely on the name in the folder.

Comment: Ok I got that. So we can include a `manifest.json` for Chrome extension and some `angularManifest.json` for PWA.